# Is there a way to use default property value if the variable not used? SCSS

Tags: css, scss-mixins

First I created the UI/UX for the application in which I extracted frequently used components, color palette, fonts, and made these into libraries along with media queries. I realized that some components are essentially the same but only differ in a few properties such as height or width. So I made component styling and components that can be customized on the go, so when it comes to the actual interface implementation I can play LEGO essentially.

The question is in the title. Can I set a default value somehow for the variables? So when It is not passed in I don't get an error, but displays as default? If yes, what is the easiest way and the best practice?

Component SCSS:

```
@mixin component($width, $height, $color) {
  .component{
     height: $height;
     width: $width;

     .somethingNested {
        color: $color;
     }
     ...
  }
   @content (if something needs to be overwritten)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s possible. You add a `: value` after the parameter.

```
@mixin component($width: 80px, $height: 80px, $color: white) {
   ...
}
```

Tips: mixin supports both positional argument and named argument.

```
// you wanna keep the default $width and $height but change $color
// with positional argument you have to repeat yourself
.foo {
  @include component(80px, 80px, pink);
}

// with named argument, just provide the $color
. foo {
  @include component($color: pink);
}
```

Ref: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#optional-arguments

Comment: Thanks. Named arguments seem to be an elegant solution and I don't need to import the library directly to the component, it is enough if I wire them in the page's SCSS. It will find the variables.

For example ``` @mixin name($shadowColorLight: $shadowLight)``` will find ```$shadowLight``` in the palette library through the page's SCSS. Don't throw an error because of an undefined variable as mixin is not executed in itself, but when in use.